# Select from table Syntax with multiple paramaters

Tags: vb.net, date, select

I need help with getting my syntax correct on the `myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText` line. I cannot seem to get the date to work as my second parameter, before it would show if a person was in a seat of my theatre, now I made more dates for shows so I need to check the seat and the date now and I cannot seem to get the date check to work:

```
Private Sub lblSeat1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSeat1.MouseEnter
        'NEED HELP ON THIS LINE BELOW
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = ("select * from seating where seat_no = " & seatNumber(0) And "select * from seating where perf_date = " & lstPerfDates.SelectedIndex)
            myDataSet.Clear()
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
            If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
                lblSeat1.BackColor = Color.Green
                ToolTipSeats.SetToolTip(lblSeat1, "Available")
            ElseIf myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
                lblSeat1.BackColor = Color.Red
                ToolTipSeats.SetToolTip(lblSeat1, myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("patron"))
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: `lstPerfDates.SelectedIndex` will be an integer not a date.  you should also use SQL parameters to save yourself much grief and anguish

Comment: Are you trying to return two separate result sets, or just one that is filtered by both parameters?   You don't use two select statements to return a single result set.

Comment: I am trying to return one result filtered by date and seat number @TabAlleman

Comment: @plutonix how would i go about getting the preset dates out of the listbox then to use for checking if i cannot use the selected index of it. If i get the index of the date would it not then go to that row in my database therefore finding the date i needed

Comment: change this: And "select * from seating where perf_date = " to this: "And perf_date = "

Comment: thanks @chuck i knew it was a quick fix i just couldn't seem to get the syntax correct

Comment: `lstPerfDates.Items(lstPerfDates.SelectedIndex)` will give you the text shown, but it will be string not Date which may cause a SQL mismatch unless you convert it; And if the user has selected nothing yet, it will cause an error

Comment: Just another suggestion apart from datatype conversions and parameterized sql: whenever you're going to run a query from .net code, try your query first directly on the database and then write it down to your .net code. The query as you were trying to write it would've never run.

Comment: @JoshPart how would I go about selecting a coloum out of my database, my query isnt running

Answer (score 0):

Changed to use parameters, and missing .item before ("patron")

```html
    Private Sub lblSeat1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSeat1.MouseEnter
        'NEED HELP ON THIS LINE BELOW
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = ("select * from seating where seat_no = @seatNumber and perf_date @perfDate")
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seatNumber", seatNumber(0))
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@perfDate", lstPerfDates.SelectedValue)
        myDataSet.Clear()
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
        If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            lblSeat1.BackColor = Color.Green
            ToolTipSeats.SetToolTip(lblSeat1, "Available")
        ElseIf myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
            lblSeat1.BackColor = Color.Red
            ToolTipSeats.SetToolTip(lblSeat1, myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).item("patron"))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType should be  `Command.Text`

Comment: Thanks Stan, I never user in-line SQL, so it is a habit!